# Run lint and tests separately inside of jest

Tags: javascript, testing, jestjs, lint

We're using `jest-runner-eslint` to run our eslint config, and then also using jest for our normal tests. Per the [suggestion in the docs](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/configuration.html#projects-array-string-projectconfig), we have our normal tests and our lint tests set up as two separate projects in the "projects field" of our config.

Unfortunately, I don't see how to run the lint tests and the "real" tests separately. Running jest with the [`--projects flag`](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/cli.html#projects-project1-projectn-) errors out because it assumes our project is a monorepo and we're trying to run tests inside of the monorepo folder.

An example:

```
$ yarn test --projects lint
yarn run v1.6.0
$ node scripts/test.js --env=jsdom --projects lint
Error: Can't find a root directory while resolving a config file path.
Provided path to resolve: lint
```

Note that we can run our tests together just fine, but the two suites can't be run separately.

### Our jest config (loosely based on create-react-app)

```
{
    "projects": [
      {
        "displayName": "test",
        "collectCoverage": true,
        "coverageDirectory": "<rootDir>/coverage",
        "collectCoverageFrom": [
          "src/**/*.{js,jsx,mjs}"
        ],
        "coverageReporters": [
          "text-summary",
          "lcov",
          "json"
        ],
        "setupTestFrameworkScriptFile": "<rootDir>/src/setupTests.js",
        "setupFiles": [
          "<rootDir>/config/polyfills.js",
          "<rootDir>/src/setupTest.js"
        ],
        "snapshotSerializers": [
          "enzyme-to-json/serializer"
        ],
        "testMatch": [
          "<rootDir>/src/**/__tests__/**/*.{js,jsx,mjs}",
          "<rootDir>/src/**/?(*.)(spec|test).{js,jsx,mjs}"
        ],
        "testEnvironment": "node",
        "testURL": "http://localhost",
        "transform": {
          "^.+\\.(js|jsx|mjs)$": "<rootDir>/node_modules/babel-jest",
          "^.+\\.css$": "<rootDir>/config/jest/cssTransform.js",
          "^(?!.*\\.(js|jsx|mjs|css|json)$)": "<rootDir>/config/jest/fileTransform.js"
        },
        "transformIgnorePatterns": [
          "[/\\\\]node_modules[/\\\\].+\\.(js|jsx|mjs)$"
        ],
        "moduleNameMapper": {
          "^react-native$": "react-native-web"
        },
        "moduleFileExtensions": [
          "web.js",
          "mjs",
          "js",
          "json",
          "web.jsx",
          "jsx",
          "node"
        ]
      },
      {
        "runner": "jest-runner-eslint",
        "displayName": "lint",
        "testMatch": [
          "<rootDir>/src/**/*.js"
        ]
      }
    ]
}
```

### Various versions:

- OS: macOS Sierra 10.12 (although I've also seen this on Ubuntu 16)
- Node: v8.11.1
- Jest: 22.4.3
- jest-runner-eslint: 0.5.0